# How can you merge two Google Documents?

Tags: google-drive

I have several large (300k - 400k) documents in Google Docs. I would like to combine them into a single document. However, when I try Copy & Paste to do this, it takes ages (because the data is going via the clipboard on my computer), and anyway the formatting goes wrong where it hits a numbered list.

Is there a way to concatenate Google docs without having to Copy & Paste?

Comment: Download copies to your local computer and you can do this from the CLI painlessly. When satisfied re-upload final compilation document.

Comment: In fact, I started with a single large Word doc, which I couldn't upload because it was too big. I split it into 6 smaller files and uploaded them all. Now I want to put it back together again. The fundamental problem is that the docs are on Google's servers, but the clipboard is on my PC.

Comment: If you are in PowerPoint and click File, then click Insert Slides and you can select the presentation you want to import to the presentation you are already editing! So simple!

Answer (score 2):

You could [Drawloop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdyEpnb6gKo) in the [Google document marketplace](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=3440+9197926189099505060). I know you can merge many docs into one.

Comment: any ideas how documents can be merged via an api?

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs now has a clipboard "in the cloud", which means it solves the problem of having to download it to your PC first.

It's called the web or [Server Clipboard](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=161768)   [image] and it works in the same way as normal copy and paste, except it's on their server side.

Comment: That's very useful to know. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to want to copy whole documents. I must be bumping into a size restriction.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps try selection smaller sections at a time to be copied to the web clipboard?